# Image scaling (KeepAspectRatioByExpanding) through OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, qt, opengl, image-scaling

I'm trying to implement **image scaling in OpenGL using only `glTexCoord2f()` and `glVertex2f()`**.

Let me explain: after loading a `QImage` and sending it to the gpu with `glTexImage2D()` I have to **perform image scaling operations based on Qt's specification**. Qt defines these 3 operations (see image below):

[image]

I think this is the only way to do it since my application is a Qt plugin and this task needs to be done inside the `paint()` method of the class. The `IgnoreAspectRatio` operation is pretty straight forward and it's working right now. The `KeepAspectRatio` gave me some trouble initially but now it's also working. Unfortunally, **`KeepAspectRatioByExpanding` is giving me headaches**.

I'm sharing what I've done so far and I appreciate your help on this issue:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "oglWindow.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    oglWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**oglWindow.cpp:**

```
#include "oglWindow.h"
#include "glwidget.h"

#include <QGridLayout>

oglWindow::oglWindow(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    GLWidget *openGL = new GLWidget(this);

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    setLayout(layout);
}

oglWindow::~oglWindow()
{
}
```

**oglWindow.h:**

```
#ifndef oglWindow_H
#define oglWindow_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_yuv_to_rgb.h"

class oglWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    oglWindow(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~oglWindow();

private:
    Ui::oglWindowClass ui;
};

#endif // oglWindow_H
```

**glwidget.cpp:**

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GL/gl.h>  
#else
    #include <GL/gl.h>
#endif

#include "glwidget.h"

#include <QDebug>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>


static const char *p_s_fragment_shader =
    "#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable\n"
    "uniform sampler2DRect tex;"
    "uniform float ImgHeight, chromaHeight_Half, chromaWidth;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "    vec2 t = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;" // get texcoord from fixed-function pipeline
    "    float CbY = ImgHeight + floor(t.y / 4.0);"
    "    float CrY = ImgHeight + chromaHeight_Half + floor(t.y / 4.0);"
    "    float CbCrX = floor(t.x / 2.0) + chromaWidth * floor(mod(t.y, 2.0));"
    "    float Cb = texture2DRect(tex, vec2(CbCrX, CbY)).x - .5;"
    "    float Cr = texture2DRect(tex, vec2(CbCrX, CrY)).x - .5;"
    "    float y = texture2DRect(tex, t).x;" // redundant texture read optimized away by texture cache
    "    float r = y + 1.28033 * Cr;"
    "    float g = y - .21482 * Cb - .38059 * Cr;"
    "    float b = y + 2.12798 * Cb;"
    "    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);"
    "}";


GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent), _frame(NULL)
{
    setAutoFillBackground(false);
    setMinimumSize(640, 480);

    /* Load 1280x768 YV12 frame from the disk */

    _frame = new QImage(1280, 768, QImage::Format_RGB888);  
    if (!_frame)
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::GLWidget !!! Failed to create _frame";
        return;
    }

    std::ifstream yuv_file("bloco.yv12", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!yuv_file.is_open())
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::GLWidget !!! Failed to load yuv file";
        return;
    }
    int yuv_file_sz = yuv_file.tellg();

    unsigned char* memblock = new unsigned char[yuv_file_sz];
    if (!memblock)
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::GLWidget !!! Failed to allocate memblock";
        return;
    }

    yuv_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    yuv_file.read((char*)memblock, yuv_file_sz);
    yuv_file.close();

    qMemCopy(_frame->scanLine(0), memblock, yuv_file_sz);

    delete[] memblock;
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
    if (_frame)
        delete _frame;
}

void GLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent OpenGL:"  << ((painter.paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL &&
                                       painter.paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL2) ? "disabled" : "enabled");   

    QGLContext* context = const_cast<QGLContext *>(QGLContext::currentContext());
    if (!context)
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent !!! Unable to retrieve OGL context";
        return;
    }
    context->makeCurrent();

    painter.fillRect(QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(1280, 768)), Qt::black);

    painter.beginNativePainting();

    /* Initialize GL extensions */
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent !!! glewInit failed with: " << err;
        return;
    }
    if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_1)  // check that the machine supports the 2.1 API.
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent !!! System doesn't support GLEW_VERSION_2_1";
        return;
    }

    /* Setting up texture and transfering data to the GPU */

    static GLuint texture = 0;
    if (texture != 0)
    {
        context->deleteTexture(texture);
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0,
            GL_LUMINANCE, _frame->width(), _frame->height() + _frame->height() / 2, 0,
            GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _frame->bits());

    assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0);

    int img_width = _frame->width();
    int img_height = _frame->height();
    int offset_x = 0;
    int offset_y = 0;

    GLfloat gl_width = width(); // GL context size
    GLfloat gl_height = height();

    /* Initialize shaders and execute them */   
    _init_shaders();

    qDebug() << "paint(): gl_width:" << gl_width << " gl_height:" << gl_height <<  
        " img:" << _frame->width() << "x" << _frame->height();

    int fill_mode = 1;
    switch (fill_mode)
    {
        case 0: // KeepAspectRatioByExpanding
        {
            // need help!
        }
        break;

        case 1: // IgnoreAspectRatio
        {
            // Nothing special needs to be done for this operation.
        }
        break;

        case 2: // KeepAspectRatio
        default:
        {
          // Compute aspect ratio and offset Y for widescreen borders
            double ratiox = img_width/gl_width;
            double ratioy = img_height/gl_height;

            if (ratiox > ratioy)
            {
                gl_height = qRound(img_height / ratiox);
                offset_y = qRound((height() - gl_height) / 2);
                gl_height += offset_y * 2;
            }
            else
            {
                gl_width = qRound(img_width / ratioy);
                offset_x = qRound((width() - gl_width) / 2);
                gl_width += offset_x * 2;
            }
        }
        break;
    }


    // Mirroring texture coordinates to flip the image vertically
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, img_height);                  glVertex2f(offset_x, gl_height - offset_y);
    glTexCoord2f(img_width, img_height);             glVertex2f(gl_width - offset_x, gl_height - offset_y);
    glTexCoord2f(img_width, 0.0f);                   glVertex2f(gl_width - offset_x, offset_y);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);                        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y);
    glEnd();

    painter.endNativePainting();
}

void GLWidget::_init_shaders()
{       
    int f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(f, 1, &p_s_fragment_shader, 0);
    glCompileShader(f);

    _shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(_shader_program, f);
    glLinkProgram(_shader_program);

    glUseProgram(_shader_program);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(_shader_program, "tex"), 0);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(_shader_program, "ImgHeight"), _frame->height());
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(_shader_program, "chromaHeight_Half"), (_frame->height() / 2) / 2);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(_shader_program, "chromaWidth"), _frame->width() / 2);   
}
```

**glwidget.h**:

```
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <QPainter>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);    

private:
    void _init_shaders();
    bool _checkShader(int n_shader_object);

    QImage* _frame;
    int _shader_program;
};
```

**And here you can [download the data file](http://www.mediafire.com/?jqymgthd2vab8ub)**.

Comment: The ideal answer needs to provide working source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply copy "keep aspect ratio" branch (provided that it is working), and just flip the ratio comparison sign, i.e.:

```
if (ratiox > ratioy)
```

becomes

```
if (ratiox <= ratioy)
```

But i'm not sure it is actually working (ratio calculations had always bugged me - and yours is tricky), and don't have Qt atm so I can't try. But that should do it. Note that the image will be centered (not left-aligned as on your image), but that can be fixed pretty easily.

**EDIT**:

Here is source code that works in GLUT application (no QT, sorry):

```
static void DrawObject(void)
{ 
    int img_width = 1280;//_frame->width();
    int img_height = 720;//_frame->height();
    GLfloat offset_x = -1;
    GLfloat offset_y = -1;

    int p_viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, p_viewport); // don't have QT :'(

    GLfloat gl_width = p_viewport[2];//width(); // GL context size
    GLfloat gl_height = p_viewport[3];//height();

    int n_mode = 0;
    switch(n_mode) {
    case 0: // KeepAspectRatioByExpanding
        {
            float ratioImg = float(img_width) / img_height;
            float ratioScreen = gl_width / gl_height;

            if(ratioImg < ratioScreen) {
                gl_width = 2;
                gl_height = 2 * ratioScreen / ratioImg;
            } else {
                gl_height = 2;
                gl_width = 2 / ratioScreen * ratioImg;
            }
            // calculate image size
        }
        break;

    case 1: // IgnoreAspectRatio
        gl_width = 2;
        gl_height = 2;
        // OpenGL normalized coordinates are -1 to +1 .. hence width (or height) = +1 - (-1) = 2
        break;

    case 2: // KeepAspectRatio
        {
            float ratioImg = float(img_width) / img_height;
            float ratioScreen = gl_width / gl_height;

            if(ratioImg > ratioScreen) {
                gl_width = 2;
                gl_height = 2 * ratioScreen / ratioImg;
            } else {
                gl_height = 2;
                gl_width = 2 / ratioScreen * ratioImg;
            }
            // calculate image size

            offset_x = -1 + (2 - gl_width) * .5f;
            offset_y = -1 + (2 - gl_height) * .5f;
            // center on screen
        }
        break;
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    // just simple ortho view, no fancy transform ...

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(ImgWidth, 0);
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(ImgWidth, ImgHeight);
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y + gl_height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, ImgHeight);
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y + gl_height);
    glEnd();
    // draw a single quad
}
```

This works by comparing **screen** aspect ratio to **image** aspect ratio. You are actually comparing ratios of image width to screen width with image height to screen height. That is suspicious at least, not to say wrong.

Also, *normalized* OpenGL coordinates (provided a simple orthogonal view) are in range (-1, -1) for lower-left corner to (1, 1) for upper right. That means *normalized* width and height are both 2, and offset is (-1, -1). The rest of the code should be self-explanatory. In case texture is flipped (I tested with kind of generic texture, not sure if it was upright), just change texture coordinates in the respective direction (swap 0s for ImgWidth (or height) and vice versa).

**EDIT2**:

Using pixel coordinates (not using normalized OpenGL coordinates) is even simpler. You can use:

```
static void DrawObject(void)
{ 
    int img_width = 1280;//_frame->width();
    int img_height = 720;//_frame->height();
    GLfloat offset_x = 0;
    GLfloat offset_y = 0;

    int p_viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, p_viewport);

    GLfloat gl_width = p_viewport[2];//width(); // GL context size
    GLfloat gl_height = p_viewport[3];//height();

    int n_mode = 0;
    switch(n_mode) {
    case 0: // KeepAspectRatioByExpanding
        {
            float ratioImg = float(img_width) / img_height;
            float ratioScreen = gl_width / gl_height;

            if(ratioImg < ratioScreen)
                gl_height = gl_width / ratioImg;
            else
                gl_width = gl_height * ratioImg;
            // calculate image size
        }
        break;

    case 1: // IgnoreAspectRatio
        break;

    case 2: // KeepAspectRatio
        {
            float ratioImg = float(img_width) / img_height;
            float ratioScreen = gl_width / gl_height;

            GLfloat orig_width = gl_width;
            GLfloat orig_height = gl_height;
            // remember those to be able to center the quad on screen

            if(ratioImg > ratioScreen)
                gl_height = gl_width / ratioImg;
            else
                gl_width = gl_height * ratioImg;
            // calculate image size

            offset_x = 0 + (orig_width - gl_width) * .5f;
            offset_y = 0 + (orig_height - gl_height) * .5f;
            // center on screen
        }
        break;
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1, -1, 0);
    glScalef(2.0f / p_viewport[2], 2.0f / p_viewport[3], 1.0);
    // just simple ortho view for vertex coordinate to pixel matching

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(img_width, 0);
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(img_width, img_height);
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y + gl_height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, img_height);
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y + gl_height);
    glEnd();
    // draw a single quad
}
```

Note that both versions of the code do use NPOT textures. To adapt the code to fit into your object, one would do something like this:

```
void GLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent OpenGL:"  << ((painter.paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL &&
                                       painter.paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL2) ? "disabled" : "enabled");   

    QGLContext* context = const_cast<QGLContext *>(QGLContext::currentContext());
    if (!context)
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent !!! Unable to retrieve OGL context";
        return;
    }
    context->makeCurrent();

    painter.fillRect(QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(1280, 768)), Qt::black);

    painter.beginNativePainting();

    /* Initialize GL extensions */
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent !!! glewInit failed with: " << err;
        return;
    }
    if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_1)  // check that the machine supports the 2.1 API.
    {
        qDebug() << "> GLWidget::paintEvent !!! System doesn't support GLEW_VERSION_2_1";
        return;
    }

    /* Setting up texture and transfering data to the GPU */

    static GLuint texture = 0;
    if (texture != 0)
    {
        context->deleteTexture(texture);
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0,
            GL_LUMINANCE, _frame->width(), _frame->height() + _frame->height() / 2, 0,
            GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _frame->bits());

    assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0);

    /* Initialize shaders and execute them */   
    _init_shaders();

    int img_width = _frame->width();
    int img_height = _frame->height();
    GLfloat offset_x = 0;
    GLfloat offset_y = 0;
    GLfloat gl_width = width(); // GL context size
    GLfloat gl_height = height();

    qDebug() << "paint(): gl_width:" << gl_width << " gl_height:" << gl_height <<  
        " img:" << _frame->width() << "x" << _frame->height();

    int fill_mode = 0;
    switch(fill_mode) {
    case 0: // KeepAspectRatioByExpanding
        {
            float ratioImg = float(img_width) / img_height;
            float ratioScreen = gl_width / gl_height;

            if(ratioImg < ratioScreen)
                gl_height = gl_width / ratioImg;
            else
                gl_width = gl_height * ratioImg;
            // calculate image size
        }
        break;

    case 1: // IgnoreAspectRatio
        break;

    case 2: // KeepAspectRatio
        {
            float ratioImg = float(img_width) / img_height;
            float ratioScreen = gl_width / gl_height;

            GLfloat orig_width = gl_width;
            GLfloat orig_height = gl_height;
            // remember those to be able to center the quad on screen

            if(ratioImg > ratioScreen)
                gl_height = gl_width / ratioImg;
            else
                gl_width = gl_height * ratioImg;
            // calculate image size

            offset_x = 0 + (orig_width - gl_width) * .5f;
            offset_y = 0 + (orig_height - gl_height) * .5f;
            // center on screen
        }
        break;
    }

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE); // might cause problems if enabled
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(img_width, 0);
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y);

        glTexCoord2f(img_width, img_height);
        glVertex2f(offset_x + gl_width, offset_y + gl_height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, img_height);
        glVertex2f(offset_x, offset_y + gl_height);
    glEnd();
    // draw a single quad

    painter.endNativePainting();
}
```

Can't guarantee this last code snippet is error-free since I don't have QT. But in case there are any typos, it should be rather straightforward to fix them.

Comment: +1 Indeed, that is how I am computing the aspect ratio right now and displaying a 1280x720 video on a 640x480 surface works perfectly. **However**, the resulting image is not being clipped correctly when video is draw on a 240x320 surface. In this case, video is displayed as 480x320, i.e., eating more space in the screen than it should. Which means I'm still missing something, and this bug is probably related to `glVertex2f` coordinates.

Comment: 480x320 - to what code are you referring here? Is it the keepAspectRatio version? If it is, I'll provide source code for a working version.

Comment: I'm talking about the KeepAspectRatioByExpanding mode, which is where I need help. According to your answer, I copied the code from KeepAspectRatio and flipped the ratio comparison sign. This provided the right AR scale, however, there's something else I need to in glVertex2f calls to make the correct clipping/cropping of the video.

Comment: @karlphillip added source code above. It's GLUT (non-QT) but should work just as well in QT. If you require full source code, I can post it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I upvoted it yesterday. However, it doesn't help me much and I was specific in the bounty statement saying that I needed working source code for my problem. That's why I shared the full source code of the application.

Comment: @karlphillip It IS the source code. All the input variables are in your code already, just copy it in! (remove code between glClearColor() and painter.endNativePainting(), except for the call to _init_shaders(), paste the body of the function I posted, and just uncomment values for img_width, img_height, gl_width and gl_height) Or do you want me to do it for you?

Comment: I used a NPOT texture, so it's not a matter of copy/pasting your code since your texture coordinates are in the range of [0..1] and the NPOT texture I used is not normalized in this range. Therefore doing `gl_width = 2;` is absolutely wrong in my case. So, to answer your comment, yes! I would love to see an answer that used my code, or as you say, *I would like you to do it for me*. =D Thanks, though.

Comment: glTexCoord2f(ImgWidth, ImgHeight); - the NPOT texture is there already (just lowercase and add _). don't you see? I have to leave for the weekend so i can't write the code now, and after that it will be too late for the bounty :). Just copy the damn code and see for yourself that it does what you need.

Comment: I copied the damn the code and all I got was a black screen. Here is what I did: on the first test I copied only the code related to `KeepAspectRatioByExpanding` and then executed the application, result: black screen. On second test, I copied that code plus the entire code related to the drawing of GL_QUAD, and again ... black screen. I understand that `glTexCoord2f()` is using the non-normalized values. **However, your code assumes that `glVertex2f()` uses normalized values**: inside the computation you do `gl_width = 2;` and `gl_height = 2;`.

Comment: @karlphillip Ok, I dit it for you :) there is a new code that doesn't use normalized vertex coordinates, but uses pixel coordinates instead. I also wrote a version that should fit into your QT code rather nicely. To your test - it is rather strange that you got black screen. Even if the calculated coordinates were normalized and QT is using pixel coordinates, it should draw at least a 1x1 pixel square. Maybe backface culling was enabled, so i disabled it for you in this new code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Simply do the same math you did with KeepAspectRatio, but this time keep the height instead of the width. You'll get a width bigger than 1, so you'll have to use the inverse of it for your texture coordinate.

---

Normalized coordinates yes/no won't matter, you just have to add these factors for the texture coordinates. For this to work I assume the image fills the whole texture (from (0,0) to (1,1); this makes it easy to multiply the values with your width/height). Texture wrapping has to be off.

Default texture coordinates:

```
(0,0)-(1,0)
|     |
(0,1)-(1,1)
```

Aspect ratios:

```
tex_ar = tex_width / tex_height; // aspect ratio for the texture being used
scr_ar = scr_width / scr_height; // aspect ratio for the quad being drawn
```

KeepAspectRatio (touch from the inside):

```
(0, 0)-----------------------(max(1, scr_ar / tex_ar), 0)
|                            |
(0, max(1, tex_ar / scr_ar))-(max(1, scr_ / tex_ar), max(1, tex_ar / scr_ar))
```

KeepAspectRatioByExpanding (touch from outside; just replace `max()` with `min()`):

```
(0, 0)-----------------------(min(1, scr_ar / tex_ar), 0)
|                            |
(0, min(1, tex_ar / scr_ar))-(min(1, scr_ / tex_ar), min(1, tex_ar / scr_ar))
```

For your case you'd just have to multiply the resulting texture coordinates with your width/height.

Comment: Could you exemplify? I'm not using normalized coordinates, as you can see. The screen size is 640x480 and the image is 1280x768.

Comment: That won't work. The computation I do in KeepAspectRatio is simply to know the Y offset to start drawing the image (and place the widescreen borders). This offset is then used in `glVertex2f()` calls to accomplish this effect. As far as I understand, for **KeepAspectRatioByExpanding** I need to mess around with the size of image, and then probably change some `glTexCoord2f()` values instead of vertex coordinates.

Comment: Super! I'm starting to get it but still couldn't figure out. Would you mind making this the perfect answer by adding the code for it? I just tried something and it didn't worked :(

Comment: Don't have QT installed atm, so maybe later. But essentially you'd just have to multiply the resulting texture coordinates with your texture width/height, e.g. the width becomes `width_to_draw = (tex_width * max(1, scr_ar / tex_ar), 0)`. Although I'm not 100% sure on how QT will handle texture coordinates bigger than 1. So it's possible you have to downscale the quad you're rendering (when not using the full width or height).

Comment: Please review the code you just shared, it doesn't seem right: `width_to_draw = (tex_width * result_of_max, 0)`

Comment: Oh, sure, just messed with editing, as I wanted to mention coordinates at first, but changed that to width later on. Just drop the `, 0`: `width_to_draw = tex_width * max(1, scr_ar / tex_ar)`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't worked as well, and I already tried every possible AR conversion I could think of. This question is quite peculiar because of the  **non** [0,1] normalized coordinates.

Comment: Just reread everything, I think you're just missing something or there's some misunderstanding. `width_to_draw` refers to the texture width to draw, not the width on screen. The width on screen would always be fixed (to the maximum).

Comment: FYI, I just set up a bounty on this question.