# Bad rendering with GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER GL_LINEAR

Tags: c++, c, opengl, filter, rendering

I'm writing an [application that uses a GLSL fragment shader to do some color conversion to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011108/image-scaling-keepaspectratiobyexpanding-through-opengl). This application uses `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` because I need to support NPOT textures.

The problem happens when a **1280x720** image is rendered **to** a smaller surface, say **640x480**.

Apparently, my **ATI** *Technologies Inc RV610 video device [Radeon HD 2400 PRO]* has problems performing minification filtering with `GL_LINEAR`:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

The red rectangle in the image below shows the exact location of the problem. Green-ish lines (4 or 5 pixels of height) are being rendered at the top of the video (black borders around the image are not part of the rendering, ok?!). Depending on the image being rendered, the color of lines change as well:

[image]

With zoom:

[image]

The problem **doesn't happens with**:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

I've tested this application **on another PC with an Intel card, and it also happens** with an *Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)*, regardless of the filtering mode being set. Coincidence?

Am I forgetting to do something in [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011108/image-scaling-keepaspectratiobyexpanding-through-opengl), could this be a driver issue? I have several machines with the same Intel card and the problem occurs in all of them. It's important to state that **this issue doesn't happen on a NVIDIA GeForce 7300**.

Comment: I also tried setting `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` to different modes, like `GL_CLAMP`, `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER`, and `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I have a suspicion what could be going on. But having some source code, both client side drawing commands and server side GLSL would help.

Comment: [The entire source code is available in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011108/image-scaling-keepaspectratiobyexpanding-through-opengl). The only thing that needs to change on that code is the call to set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` as `GL_LINEAR`.

Comment: We could also go to a chat session and I could follow your instructions to perform the tests if it's easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sourcecode I see the following in the shader:

```
     float CbY = ImgHeight + floor(t.y / 4.0);
     float CrY = ImgHeight + chromaHeight_Half + floor(t.y / 4.0);
```

I have no idea, why you add ImgHeight to the texture coordinates, because all it'd do was wrap around if that's the texture height. Then you're packing the different color components into a single texture. So you must take extra care to correctly calculate offsets. That one pixel high line colored off is a indication, that your texture coordinates are wrong. GL_NEAREST coerces to integers, but with GL_LINEAR they must match. I suggest replacing `floor` with `round`.