# Window does not render in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I`m using QMainWindow with

```
setStyleSheet("background : transparent;" );
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```

And I create QDeclarativeView with viewport as QGlWidget.
After compilation, I see a bug. The window is not is rendered(
This causes the third line.
Without QGlWidget window is rendering.

EDIT:
This is  minimal reproduce [link](http://rghost.ru/36726015)

Comment: Only a minimal example that reproduces your problem can help you in this case. Some time ago I asked a [question that shared some code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9011108/176769) to accomplish that and a little more.

Comment: added minimal reproduce.

Comment: Beautiful *hello world* app, fullscreen, white background, label in the middle, no borders in the window. What exactly did you expect it should do? By the way, what Qt version are you using? I ran your app on Mac OS X with Qt 4.7.4

Comment: I`m using Qt 4.8 on Windows 7 and Window not render

Comment: *but has icon on  Windows Taskbar

Answer (score 2):

The minimal example worked perfectly on my Mac OS X with Qt 4.7.4.

If it's not working on Windows with Qt 4.8 it may be either a cross-platform bug or some problem with the newest Qt.

I suggest you downgrade to Qt 4.7.4 and try again.