# How to delete content from QPixMap

Tags: qt

I creating simple image viewer for education purpose. 
I have class ScreenImage which including QPixMap for load image. For load image from drive I use QPixMap::load().

```
class ScreenImage : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
          ...

    bool loadImage(const QString &filename);


    QScrollArea *_pScrollArea;
    QLabel *_pLabel;
    QPixmap *_pPixmap;

    ...
};
```

The question: how to delete already loaded into QPixMap image? And if I loaded new image in the same QPixMap then memory for previously loaded image will lost? (will memory leak)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to allocate a `QPixmap` on the heap. Think of `QPixmap` as an `int`. Would you use a pointer to `int` in your class?

Hence:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
     QPixmap m_pixmap;
public:
     void loadFile(const QString &path) {
           m_pixmap.load(path);
     }
};
```

is correct and doesn't leak anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using QImage. QImage uses [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html)
of memory, so you don't have to new or deep copy the image when using it. To de-allocate the QImage, simply assign it to an empty image:

```
QImage img;
...
img = QImage();
```

For further understanding I suggest reading about the [difference between QImage & QPixmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307860/what-is-the-difference-between-qimage-and-qpixmap). The short of it is: don't use QPixmap outside of the gui thread.