# Rendering SDL_surface on a QWidget in a platform-independent manner

Tags: qt, sdl

I have a `SDL_surface` that plays a video in its own window. I want this window to be rendered on a `QWidget`. I want a generic solution because my targets are OSX, Windows and Linux.

I've come across [2 solutions](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_GUI) summarized as below:

1. **The Window ID hack** involves setting `SDL_WINDOWID` to the QWidget's id so SDL *pushes* pixels on the QWidget. Here is an [Example Qt snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144953/492857) from a related thread.

   However, this doesn't work on OS X and is not guaranteed to work on all Win and Linux platforms.
2. **Manually copying** from non-window SDL_surface to QWidget.

   Found some [example code for Gtk+](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_GUI) but nothing for Qt so far. The idea is to push the video to memory and pull it from QWidget. Surely one shouldn't use a QImage to render each frame. So how would one implement this copying?

There are possible duplicate questions but my question is more specific about platform-independence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the pixels from the `SDL_Surface` and create a `QImage` with it, then use a `QPainter` to draw the `QImage` on the widget.

Comment: Won't the overhead associated with creating a QImage make it inefficient, like I said in my question?

Comment: I don't have any, but I might write some later today. But your question is not tagged as C/C++ ...

Comment: I'm trying to code it as well. Will update [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261275/efficient-conversion-from-sdl-surface-to-qpixmap) when I'm done, if you are interested

Comment: Just to be clear, there's really no conversion of data going on in the approach I suggest. The bottleneck is really drawing the stuff on the screen. =/ To make it faster, [render the data to a `QGLContext` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194604/high-performance-qimage-output-to-display/11194780#11194780).

Comment: You mean when I initialize QImage, it doesn't deep copy the RGB array? Or you meant that such a memory copy is not intensive anyway?

Comment: FYI got [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11261901/492857) to how to transform SDL_Surface to QImage. It's working. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction