# Efficient conversion from SDL_Surface to QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, sdl

I need to extract pixel information and populate a QPixmap to be used in my Qt program.

I am currently doing this in a 2-step process.

- SDL_Surface to Windows .bmp using `SDL_SaveBMP()`
- .bmp to QImage
- QImage to QPixmap

I am storing the intermediate .bmp in memory. But overall, I am not happy with this approach because it involves file-format conversion overheads related to .bmp

Any better suggestion?

**Edit:** Sharing the final working code, from jrok's answer plus experimenting with pixel formats

```
SDL_Surface *screen = ... /* Whatever surface you want to copy from */
SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE,
                       screen->w, screen->h,
                       24, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
SDL_BlitSurface(screen,NULL, surface,NULL);
QImage img(static_cast<uchar*>(surface->pixels),
                       surface->w, surface->h, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of [`QImage` constructors](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-5) takes raw image data. You can pass it `pixels` pointer from SDL_Surface structure:

```
SDL_Surface* surf = /* get surface */

QImage img(static_cast<uchar*>(surf->pixels), surf->w, surf->h, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

The last parameter will depend on the [SDL_PixelFormat](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_PixelFormat) of your SDL_Surface.

Then you can simply make `QPixmap` from `QImage`:

```
QPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
```

[QPixmap::fromImage() reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qpixmap.html#fromImage)

Comment: Thanks. Got it working using this approach but with a small change. If the SDL_Surface has a pixel format that cannot be converted to QImage using any of the QImage formats, you should blit it to a new SDL_Surface created by SDL_CreateRGBSurface()