# Displaying an image with QImage and OpenCV

Tags: qt, image-processing, opencv, qt5, qimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest method to convert IplImage IPL_DEPTH_32S to QImage Format_RGB32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371540/fastest-method-to-convert-iplimage-ipl-depth-32s-to-qimage-format-rgb32)

I am facing a weird problem in displaying image with Qt...I read a video frame using OpenCV and convert it into RGB from BGR.

```
video >> frameOrg;
cvtColor(frameOrg,frameOrg,CV_BGR2RGB);
```

then I select a ROI on the image using crop style..

```
frame = frameOrg(roi);
```

I send the selected ROI over signal/slot to a widget for display..the `paintEvent()` of the display uses

```
image = QImage((const unsigned char*)frame.data,frame.cols,
               frame.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);

QRectF target(0.0,0.0,image.width(),image.height());
QRectF source(0.0,0.0,image.width(),image.height());
QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawImage(target,image,source);
```

But whenever I choose some combination of odd valued width and height of the ROI I get a weird display as shown below...
**ORIGINAL IMAGE**

[image: full image when displayed]

**IMAGE OF THE ROI SELECTED**

[image: image of selected roi]

Do I need to do some modifications? Is windows 7 having some problem in displaying? The same ROI when displayed with `imshow()` displays correctly...any one help me..thanx in advance...

**ACTUAL CODE WHICH WORKS**

```
image = QImage((const unsigned char*)frame.data,frame.cols,
               frame.rows,frame.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Comment: Isn't a +1 missing somewhere ? A row `i` is always left-shifted by `i` columns, which is just a propagation of the the previous row missing 1 column.

Comment: this is not always occurring...for some combination only I am getting such weird results...

Comment: Explicitly indicate some of those combinations then.

Comment: I've talked about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11371701/176769).

Comment: @karlphillip this question is clearly not a duplicate of that one. It is dealing with an entirely different problem than the one described here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a padding issue. You haven't said what the type of your `frame` variable is, but `IPLImage` has a `widthStep` field. Use this constructor for QImage

```
QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )
```

and pass `widthStep` as the `bytesPerLine` parameter.

Comment: +1 I agree, this typically looks like a 4-byte alignment issue